# Duplicating the rownode on button click in ag grid

Tags: ag-grid-ng2

How I can clone the row in AG grid, also cloning should have the same data whichever row was cloned. Although data can be further editable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, clone the data into a new object:

```
const originalRecord: RecordType;
...
const newRecord: RecordType = {...originalRecord};
```

(You will need to use a different approach to duplicating the record if you want to include methods or you need a deep copy).

Next, add the new record to the grid:

```
  this.grid.api.updateRowData({add: [newRecord]});
```

There's an example of creating new rows here: [Updating with transaction](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#example-updating-with-transaction).

Comment: Thanks I used _.cloneDeep for this